# Fedora 18 - Connection Manager's OpenVPN configuration File

Tags: linux, fedora

Where does the Connection Manager on Fedora 18 store the OpenVPN configuration that the GUI produced?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ ?

Comment: Under this directory, there will be files that are named after your connection. Network Manager does not store OpenVPN connection information in an .ovpn format. Perform a cat on the file to see the contents and information in the bracket are OpenVPN parameters [vpn]